# How can one pass an argument to docker run with spaces

Tags: bash, docker, args

This may be specific to the argument parsing done by https://github.com/atmoz/sftp/blob/master/entrypoint#L36

But I am trying to create a directory with spaces:

Some examples I've tried:

---

```
docker run -d  atmoz/sftp:alpine-3.7 user:password:::Inbound - Test Dir
...
[entrypoint] Parsing user data: "user:password:::Inbound"
Creating mailbox file: No such file or directory
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Inbound
[entrypoint] Parsing user data: "-"
[entrypoint] ERROR: Invalid username "-", do not match required regex pattern: [A-Za-z0-9._][A-Za-z0-9._-]{0,31}
```

---

```
docker run -d atmoz/sftp:alpine-3.7 user:password:::"Inbound - Test Dir"
...
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Inbound
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/-
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Test
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Dir
```

---

```
docker run -d atmoz/sftp:alpine-3.7 "user:password:::Inbound - Test Dir"
...
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Inbound
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/-
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Test
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Dir
```

---

```
docker run -d atmoz/sftp:alpine-3.7 user:password:::Inbound\ -\ Test\ Dir
...
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Inbound
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/-
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Test
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Dir
```

---

```
 docker run -d atmoz/sftp:alpine-3.7 user:password:::'Inbound - Test Dir'
...
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Inbound
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/-
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Test
[entrypoint] Creating directory: /home/user/Dir
```

Comment: The arguments are just parsed by [entrypoint](https://github.com/atmoz/sftp/blob/master/entrypoint) in the docker container. It get's read into ${args[2]} [here](https://github.com/atmoz/sftp/blob/master/entrypoint#L55) and then splitted around [here](https://github.com/atmoz/sftp/blob/master/entrypoint#L100). It's strange, they are splitted using `IFS=, read` and the whole procedure seems to be very carefull. Try to overwrite docker entrypoint with `bash -x /entrypoint` to see what's going on. `read` has no `-r` flag,you can use it.Try double escaping `'user:password:::Inbound\ -\ Test\ Dir'`

Comment: The linked code is buggy, pure and simple. `for dirPath in ${dirArgs[@]}` on line 101 simply cannot accommodate path names containing whitespace.

Comment: @KamilCuk sadly, the double escaping didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like this is a bug in the `createUser` function, due to lack of double-quotes around various variables containing the directory name. There's no way to work around this by adding escapes, quotes, etc in the argument; you really have to fix the script that's causing the problem.

I haven't tested this, but adding double-quotes appropriately in lines 98-111 like this may do it:

```
# Make sure dirs exists
if [ -n "$dir" ]; then
    IFS=',' read -a dirArgs <<< "$dir"    # Quotes added here
    for dirPath in "${dirArgs[@]}"; do    # And here
        dirPath="/home/$user/$dirPath"
        if [ ! -d "$dirPath" ]; then
            log "Creating directory: $dirPath"
            mkdir -p "$dirPath"               # And here
            chown -R $uid:users "$dirPath"    # And here
        else
            log "Directory already exists: $dirPath"
        fi
    done
fi
```

It's possible there are other places in the script that're contributing to the problem, but at the very least the above changes need to be made. Also, the first line I added quotes to only needs them on some versions of bash, but it's best to have them there just in case.

p.s. line 39 should probably also be fixed:

```
IFS=':' read -a args <<< "$1"
```

The current version uses `$@`, which is just weird. The function only ever gets passed one argument, and some versions of bash will misparse that if it's not quoted, so the version I have is a better way to do it.

[shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) points out a bunch of other dubious things, but that's the only other one I see that should matter.

Comment: Thanks, I've suggested this as a patch to the authors and credited you. https://github.com/atmoz/sftp/issues/143

Comment: @DavidGoate I'd recommend testing it to make sure it solves the problem (& doesn't create any new ones -- I'm pretty sure not, but best to check), and noting the results in your bug report.

Comment: While there may be a bug in OP's code, the underlying question is how to include spaces in the run command. As literally everyone else who reads this is looking for an answer *to that question* for their own, different code, this assertion/response is not useful generally. Workarounds are no good for the community, only the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in the latest release based on this thread: https://github.com/atmoz/sftp/issues/143